# Pandas resampling: how to generate offset rules string from TimeDelta

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to generate the offset rule string accepted by [DataFrame.resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) (e.g. 'T', '3W', '2D', [etc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)) starting from a TimeDelta or another object representing a time frequency?

I know that DataFrame.resample can accept a TimeDelta, but I like to know how to generate the string programmatically without having to invent my own function.

```
td = pd.TimeDelta('3min')
str(td)
```

Output

```
'0 days 00:03:00'
```

Actually I would like to obtain an offset rule string: e.g. '3T'

Comment: could you give an example of what you mean? maybe even link to `.resample` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) explain that str(t)

> Returns a string in the form [D day[s], ][H]H:MM:SS[.UUUUUU], where D is negative for negative t.

You wanted to know if `timedelta` offers support for output like '3W' without having a user function (trivially) format its numeric output into such a format. No, it does not offer such support.

You may find [to_perioddelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_perioddelta.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_perioddelta) helpful when you write such a function.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else needs to write their own function like myself, here is the code:

```
def timedelta_to_string(timedelta):
    """
    Converts a pandas.Timedelta to a string rappresentation
    compatible with pandas.Timedelta constructor format
    """
    c = timedelta.components
    format = ''
    if c.days != 0:
        format += '%dD' % c.days
    if c.hours > 0:
        format += '%dh' % c.hours
    if c.minutes > 0:
        format += '%dm' % c.minutes
    if c.seconds > 0:
        format += '%ds' % c.seconds
    if c.milliseconds > 0:
        format += '%dms' % c.milliseconds
    if c.microseconds > 0:
        format += '%dus' % c.microseconds
    if c.nanoseconds > 0:
        format += '%dns' % c.nanoseconds
return format
```